# HTOL vs VTOL first stages

Tags: launch, spacecraft, launch-vehicle, engineering, orbital

For a generic launch vehicle, would Horizontal Take off be better than VTOL like most orbital launch vehicles?

Comment: What benefits do bringing wings to the equation gain us in terms of launch capability?

Comment: They don't. Though good point. 
This is one of the reasons I dislike the Shuttle program. Wings are a waste of mass.
Though more to your comment: Faster acceleration. Specifically, due to the lack of trying to compensate for 9.81ms^-2 using the same engines you are using for getting to orbit. Wings provide lift, or alternatively, as I had assumed but not stated, to simplify the question, a lifting body such as MUSTARD (though that was VTOL)
Thanks!

Comment: Thing is, most rockets have a steep ascent profile precisely because they want to punch through the draggiest part of the atmosphere quickly - Falcon 9 first stage gets you to 8000KM/s at 90KM altitude and 100KM down range before it separates. Then the relatively tiny second stage gets you to 27000KM/s and 160KM altitude, which it can do because of the hugely lower drag from the thin atmosphere. For wings to be useful, you need to be in that thicker air, which means more drag for longer...  Rockets dont really have a problem with gravity, its drag and lack of speed that they want to overcome.

Comment: Wings plus airbreathing engines definitely gets you something.

Comment: the only advantage I can think of for horizontal takeoff is that you're taking advantage of wings, which give a sort of mechanical advantage.  A vertical takeoff rocket has to have a thrust-to-weight ratio of better than one; a horizontal takeoff rocket doesn't, and so can probably run at generally lower powers for a while, at the penalty of also likely not accumulating much energy either due to drag limitations.

Comment: If you are remaining within the atmosphere to make use of aerodynamic lift, you are limited to much *lower* accelerations, otherwise aerodynamic forces and heating become too much of a problem. The theoretical advantage of aerodynamic lift is that it allows the vehicle to climb and accelerate with weaker engines, but with the high T/W ratio of rocket engines and the high wing mass, landing gear mass, structural penalties, and additional costs of horizontal flight, this hasn't been demonstrated to be an actual advantage.

Comment: @ikrase mainly billions more in development budget and decades of development time, and far higher system complexity.

Comment: Would you consider air-launched like Pegasus or Virgin Orbit's offerings "horizontal take off"?

Comment: Not really. My intent was for a fully self-contained system.
However, there is a technicality. If the first stage is say, a huge wave rider, and the second is a compact Pegasus style launcher, then this is valid.
Basically it can't use a Boeing, both stages have to be only built for speed.
For instance this would rule out an "interim HOTOL" design.
[link](http://www.astronautix.com/i/interimhotol.html)
Thanks for asking!